# How to set app launcher image from drawable folder?

Tags: android, icons, launcher

Instead of using multiple images of multiple sizes in different folders like mdpi,ldpi,hdpi etc, can i put single image in drawable folder for app launcher icon so that i can reduce app size. What should i do for that.

Comment: Launcher icons represent a handful of KB of space. Having worse-looking launcher icons would not seem to be worth the effort. That being said, delete any densities that you do not want to ship, and Android will pick another nearby density's edition of the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, try changing your manifest from the mipmap directory to the drawable one. If it doesn't work, I suggest just using a mipmap version with all the different sizes. If you think preparing the different icon sizes is difficult, it's not:

When you add the launcher icon, android studio will offer you to auto generated the various densities for you while you're in the image selection bit. So, you only have to add one image, incase you thought you had to resize them.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,generate icon of largest size ,which u think u may need anywhere ,and put that in your drawable folder. Android will automatically resize and use it according to requirement , This way you can effectively have just one image and let android handle sizing